# ネットワークかレポジトリが原因でエラーがでています。

Tags: linux, ubuntu

通知領域に！と三角の赤い色の通知がでました。
Ubuntu 14.04を使っていますが、ネットワークかレポジトリが原因でエラーがでています。
アップデートを試みましたが最新の状態ということで何も起きませんでした。どのようにしたらエラーを回避できますか。

> The update information is outdated.This may be caused by network problems or by a repository that is no longer available.Please update manually selecting 'Show updates'from the indicator menu,and watching for any failing repositories.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/481789/unknown-error-in-my-system14-04
を試したところ

> @ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:upubuntu-com/office
>   [sudo] password for aaa:     詳しい情報:
>   https://launchpad.net/~upubuntu-com/+archive/ubuntu/office [ENTER]
>   を押すと続行します。ctrl-c で削除をキャンセルできます
>
> @ubuntu:~$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:upubuntu-com/office sudo: ppa-purge:
>   command not found 
>   @ubuntu:~$

とでてきました。

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

でどうにかなりましたけど

> @ubuntu:~$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:upubuntu-com/office Updating packages
>   lists W:
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/jon-severinsson/ffmpeg/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources
>   の取得に失敗しました  404  Not Found
>
> W:
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/jon-severinsson/ffmpeg/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages
>   の取得に失敗しました  404  Not Found
>
> W:
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/jon-severinsson/ffmpeg/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages
>   の取得に失敗しました  404  Not Found
>
> W:
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/directhex/monoxide/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources
>   の取得に失敗しました  404  Not Found
>
> W:
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/directhex/monoxide/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages
>   の取得に失敗しました  404  Not Found
>
> W:
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/directhex/monoxide/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages
>   の取得に失敗しました  404  Not Found
>
> E: いくつかのインデックスファイルのダウンロードに失敗しました。これらは無視されるか、古いものが代わりに使われます。 
>   Warning:   apt-get update failed for some reason 
>   PPA to be removed: upubuntu-com office 
>   Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: upubuntu-com office

なんか警告出てますけど大丈夫ですか？

追記

今朝確認したところまたエラーが出ていました。
重篤ではないので放置します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

そのエラーでそのまま検索すると、stak overflowにいくつか答えがありましたがそちらは試してみましたか？
下のurlは、それらの一つです。
https://askubuntu.com/questions/481789/unknown-error-in-my-system14-04

Comment: 少し勘違いしていたので、先ほどのコメントを削除させて頂きました。警告が出ていますが大丈夫だと思います。URL先の人も信頼できるパッケージがなかったためエラーが出たようですが解決出来たみたいです。
URL先にあったそのコマンド以下のコマンドは全て実行されましたか？

Comment: 今のところ問題なく動いています。インストールの行は見落としましたが、全部実行したと思います

Comment: それで大丈夫だと思いますよ。とりあえず解決したみたいなので良かったです。